# Installing ubuntu-mate-desktop on 16.04, blueman configure issues

Tags: apt, 16.04, dpkg

On Ubuntu 16.04 I have tried to install `ubuntu-mate-desktop` with `sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-mate-desktop` but unfortunately I have encountered the error:

```
Fetched 223 kB in 2s (106 kB/s)        
(Reading database ... 356281 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgee-0.8-2_0.18.1-0ubuntu1~16.04~valateam0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgee-0.8-2:amd64 (0.18.1-0ubuntu1~16.04~valateam0) over (0.18.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Setting up blueman (2.0.4-1ubuntu2) ...
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
 * Reloading system message bus config...                                                        Failed to open connection to "system" message bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package blueman (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-mate-desktop:
 ubuntu-mate-desktop depends on blueman; however:
  Package blueman is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-mate-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libgee-0.8-2:amd64 (0.18.1-0ubuntu1~16.04~valateam0) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 blueman
 ubuntu-mate-desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried running:

```
sudo apt-get install -y blueman ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

and:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and still no resolution is in sight.

Answer (score 2):

It fails to restart DBUS service when configuring `blueman` package:

1. Open for editing `/var/lib/dpkg/info/blueman.postinst`
2. Comment one of these line

   ```
   #set -e
   ```

   or

   ```
   #invoke-rc.d dbus reload
   ```

Comment: `#invoke-rc.d dbus reload` followed by `dpkg --configure -a` worked for me.