# Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) --> Blueman

Tags: apt, dpkg, blueman

I am trying to install xubuntu-desktop on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system running on Windows 10. I first met the error: tasksel: apt-get failed (100).

Following other threads I ran `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and while that did not change much I tried to `run sudo dpkg --configure -a`, giving an error related to blueman:

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw853.png)

This thread ([Installing ubuntu-mate-desktop on 16.04, blueman configure issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837817/installing-ubuntu-mate-desktop-on-16-04-blueman-configure-issues)) suggested to comment a line in the blueman.postint file. It might be basic, but how do I do within the Ubuntu terminal? Are there any better options to fix the issue?

Comment: Does *"Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system running on Windows 10"* mean Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion

Comment: OK so that makes things quite a bit more complicated I think - AFAIK you need an external (i.e. Windows) X server (see for example [Run ubuntu-desktop on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162808/run-ubuntu-desktop-on-wsl-ubuntu-18-04-lts)) - and I'm not sure the bluetooth hardware is exposed to WSL at all

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the thread you referred me to is actually exactly the thing I am trying to do, i.e. couple my ubuntu WSL to VcXsrv. If I delete the previous failed xubuntu-desktop files and try installing again ubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-desktop or ubuntu-mate-desktop I always get the same issue: ```Errors were encountered while processing: blueman``` ```E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```. The thread I referred to in my first post says that this can be improved by commenting a line, but if I open the file blueman.postint in nano or vim it appears empty.